# does "magnetism" refers to "spirit" and "human" or not?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

does "magnetism" refers to "spirit" and "human" or not?

> That they still lived and still loved was the constant message from
>   the beyond, accompanied by many material tests, which confirmed the
>   wavering faith of the new adherents of the movement. When asked for
>   their methods of working and the laws which governed them, the answers
>   were from the beginning exactly what they are now: that it was a
>   matter concerned with **human and spirit magnetism**; that some who
>   were richly endowed with this physical property were mediums; that
>   this endowment was not necessarily allied to morality or intelligence;
>   and that the condition of harmony was especially necessary to secure
>   good results.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the author means "human magnetism and spirit magnetism".